# Replace all occurrences in page html, with php

Tags: php

have a html page, need to replace some links applying a function.

example in a html found this links

```
www.terra.com/w/a.htm
www.terra.com/w/b.htm
www.terra.com/asads
```

need to change [www.terra.com/w001/a.htm](http://www.terra.com/w001/a.htm), [www.terra.com/w435/b.htm](http://www.terra.com/w435/b.htm), but not [www.terra.com/asads](http://www.terra.com/asads)

use the function to calculate a result number to add to `w(NUMBER)`

```
        function cryp ($str)
        {
            return str_pad((hexdec(substr(md5(basename($str)), 0, 10)) % 1000), 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }
```

I have been tried with this function but it doesn't works

```
    function makeLinks($str, $w) {
      $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https)\\:\\/\\/[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\\/\\S*)?/";
      $urls = array();
      $urlsToReplace = array();
      if (preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $str, $urls)) {
          $numOfMatches = count($urls[0]);
          $numOfUrlsToReplace = 0;
          for ($i = 0;$i < $numOfMatches;$i++) {
              $alreadyAdded = false;
              $numOfUrlsToReplace = count($urlsToReplace);
              for ($j = 0;$j < $numOfUrlsToReplace;$j++) {
                  if ($urlsToReplace[$j] == $urls[0][$i]) {
                      $alreadyAdded = true;
                  }
              }
              if ((!$alreadyAdded) AND  (strpos($urls[0][$i], $w) !== false)){
                  array_push($urlsToReplace, $urls[0][$i]);
              }
          }
          $numOfUrlsToReplace = count($urlsToReplace);
          for ($i = 0;$i < $numOfUrlsToReplace;$i++) {
              
              $urlsToReplace[$i] = str_replace("/w/", "/w".cryp($urlsToReplace[$i])."/", $urlsToReplace[$i]);
        
            $str = str_replace($urlsToReplace[$i], $urlsToReplace[$i]."cocococo", $str);
          }
          return $str;
      } else {
          return $str;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://www.terra.com/w/a.htm';

list($first, $path, $page) = explode('/', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));

if ($page) {
  $new_path = cryp($path);
  $new_url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME).'://'.parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST).'/'.$new_path.'/'.$page;
  echo $new_url;//http://www.terra.com/w197/a.htm
}
```